# How to configure Stripe Connect on Django to collect fees on transactions?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

After several research I've come to a conclusion that **Stripe Connect** documentation on Django wasn't really furnished. I've been struggling to create a simple marketplace using the Standalone Package (OAuth).

The goal of the plateforme is to let users do transactions between each other and collect fees on each charges. To achieve this I'm using **django-allauth** and **stripe**.

I've set up django-allauth so users can already create an account on stripe and login on my website. The problem I'm facing now is on how to charge users between each other.

Here is the error I get when I'm trying to make a payment from two different accounts, UserA (customer) to UserB (publisher/seller) :

> stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_*************: The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account.

**Here is my views**

```
customer_id = request.user.profile.stripe_id

if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        gig = Gig.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('gig_id'))
    except Gig.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')


    token = request.POST['stripeToken']

    # Create a charge: this will charge the user's card
    try:
        customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
        customer.sources.create(source=token)

        destination_id = gig.user.socialaccount_set.get().uid 

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=5000,  # Amount in cents
            currency="chf",
            customer=customer,
            description=gig.title,
            application_fee=123,
            destination=destination_id, #'acct_**************'
        )

    except stripe.error.CardError as e:
        # The card has been declined
        pass
```

`Gig` is my product model and `Profile` is my profile model where I keep `stripe_id`

I've read the documentation and I'm providing the account destination with the seller's destination id. Am I missing something ? Why do I get this error ?

Comment: i did the same why i am getting error ` return super(StripeObject, self).__getitem__(k)
KeyError: 'sources' ` on here `customer.sources.create(source=token)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Success**, the first payment went through ! Here's a short tutorial on how to setup Stripe connect:

For the standalone package, here is what I use **Django-allauth** and **Stripe**.

Things you need to know for making it work on test mode :

a. configure django-allauth with stripe *(create a customer each time an account is created)*.

b. You cannot set the destination with the admin account destination ID if it's the one you used to create the app otherwise you'll get this error :

> stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_*************: The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account.

c. You need to make sure to put this code on your settings as you can proceed to do charges or transfers only if the scope is set to read_write, put this code in your settings.py

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'stripe': {
        'SCOPE': ['read_write'],
    } 
}
```

d. give a `stripe_id` to your profile model in order to give a unique id to each connected user.

e. Show the checkout form on the template.

Know that you'll probably have to create a second test account in order to make your payment in dev mode because you cannot use the admin account.

Don't hesitate to use the `views.py` code in the question.

Enjoy stripe connect on your marketplace !

Comment: @KimmoHintikka Glad to help :) I spent hours swearing on that when I was on this project